# MySQL - InnoDB indexing varchar or indexing multiple varchars

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

Hello everyone i am planing to create table with 10 columns, which should be at least 10,000,000 rows, and inside of it, i would have column `description  - VARCHAR(600)` and index on it.

So the question is, would it be faster to query `LIKE` on that column - VARCHAR(600), or it would be faster to split the description in 6 columns with 100 characters and indexing them with `LIKE` and `OR`..

For example: `description - VARCHAR(600) INDEX`

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE "%something%"
```

**or it would be faster to split `description`** in 6 columns like `desc1`, `desc2`,..`desc6` with `VARCHAR(100) INDEX` - each of them and use following query:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `desc1` LIKE "%something%" OR `desc1` LIKE "%something%" OR `desc3` LIKE "%something%" OR `desc4` LIKE "%something%" OR `desc5` LIKE "%something%" OR `desc6` LIKE "%something%"
```

Just wondering before i start creating the database..

Best regards and Thanks to everyone!

Comment: what do you want to search for? unstructured data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no difference at all . . . well, very little.  The query is going to have to do a full table scan, because the `like` pattern starts with a wildcard ("%").

If you care about performance, you should probably rephrase the problem as a full-text search.  Start with the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as i care about performance, i just have another question when you mentioned full-text search, should i also use full-text search on a column that has maximum of 40 characters (VARCHAR[40])..

Comment: @Ultrazz008 . . . It depends on what you are searching for.  Full text search is focused on *words* in the column, not substrings.

Comment: Got it, then the like is better for this option... But for above one, i will use full-text indexing, thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `LIKE '%something%'` (that is, `LIKE` with leading wildcard), then

- A single column.  (Less work than 6 `LIKEs`, plus `ORs`)  Also, what would you do about `something` that happens to be spread across two chunks?
- No index on that column (because of the leading wildcard, the index would not be use)